# Steps to calculate, $(\frac{5}{3})^{-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So first I calculate,

$(\frac{5}{3})^{3}$

Which gives me,

$(\frac{27}{125})$

But where should I go from there?

Comment: Nowhere; you're done. (The fraction doesn't reduce.)

Comment: You stop right there. Because you already calculates $\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)^{-3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finite non-zero $a,b$ $$\left(\frac ab\right)^{-m}=\frac1{\left(\frac ab\right)^m}=\left(\frac ba\right)^m=\frac{b^m}{a^m}$$

OR

$$\left(\frac ab\right)^{-m}=\frac{a^{-m}}{b^{-m}}=\frac1{a^m}/\frac1{b^m}=\frac{b^m}{a^m}$$